# Web service and form translator

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, webforms

My project is to write a web service and a web form that consumes it. It should have two text boxes and a button. The user enters an text speak acronym in the first text box and presses the button. The web service compares the textbox1 entry against a dictionary file, and displays the resulting full word in the second text box. This is the code I have so far and I am really struggling to get it to work, any help would be appreciated. At this point I have 'Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected' error. Here are the two files i have.

Default.aspx.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:/dictionary.csv")))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] tokens = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                _dictionary[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localhost.Service obj = new localhost.Service();
        TextBox1.Text = (obj.Translate());
    }
}
```

Service.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;


[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string Translate(string input)
{
    string output;
    if(_dictionary.TryGetValue(input, out output))
        return output;

    // Obviously you might not want to throw an exception in this basis example,
    // you might just go return "ERROR".  Up to you, but those requirements are
    // beyond the scope of the question! :)
    throw new Exception("Sinatra doesn't know this ditty");
}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the question is still unanswered. But here are my suggestions.

In the web service file i.e. say Service1.cs you are not declaring the _dictionary object. So you will be moving the dictionary object declaration and initialization in the constructor of the service.

Some thing like this below.

```
 public WebService1()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:/dictionary.csv")))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] tokens = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                _dictionary[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Also in the split method I would assume you wanted to use the comma instead of the semicolon(that was used in your sample).

And then in the consumption of the service, you would do some thing like this below. I was not sure what you were trying to do using the localhost object in your sample.

```
 ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient obj = new WebService1SoapClient();
        TextBox2.Text =  obj.Translate(TextBox1.Text);
```

Hope this helps.

-Davood.